# How to find the index number of an array, while already looping through it in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have something similar to this:

```
for (@array) {
    print "The value : $_ \n";
    print "The current index : ???";
}
```

But I do not understand, how can I get the current index of `@array` when looping like this. Please help :)

Comment: @toolic That's what I thought to use. But I was trying to search, if there is something built in available. I didn't find any, so posted.

Answer (score 9):

Don't loop over the array's elements; loop over the array's indexes instead.

```
for (0 .. $#array) {
  print "The value : $array[$_]\n";
  print "The current index : $_\n";
}
```

Given an array called `@array`, the special variable `$#array` will contain the index of the last element in the array. Therefore the range `0 .. $#array` will produce a list of all of the indexes in the array.

Answer (score 4):

Since Perl 5.12 you can use [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) for arrays (before it worked only with hashes).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(a b c);

while( my ($idx, $val) = each @array ) {
    print "idx=$idx, val=$val\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
idx=0, val=a
idx=1, val=b
idx=2, val=c
```

Comment: Mine is perl 5.10.1. I see : Type of arg 1 to each must be hash (not private array) at test.pl line 8, near "@array ) "
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Damn. Bad luck. Then you have to use a separate `$index` variable.

Comment: I wonder if that use of `each` has the same pitfalls regarding the internal counter as it does on hashes.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yeah, I am using something like that now. Thank you so much. Thanks Dave :)

Comment: @simbabque Interesting question. I've no idea and only rarely used `each` with arrays. And when, it was as simple as above.

Comment: The problem is that if you put that in a function and call it several times, the internal hash pointer might shoot you in the foot.